# jqGrid tree grid - not showing?

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid, treegrid

There is a concept that eludes me ... I can't figure out what is it I do wrong !!! 
I have the following JSON:

```
{
 "data":[
  {
     "amount":150.00,
     "dealDate":"10/18/15 11:53 AM",
     "dealName":"Deal 1",
     "id":"1",
     "parent":"null", 
     "level":"0", 
     "isLeaf":false, 
     "loaded":true        
  },
  {
     "amount":100.00,
     "dealDate":"10/16/15 11:53 AM",
     "dealName":"Deal 1a",
     "id":"2",
     "parent":"1", 
     "level":"1", 
     "isLeaf":true, 
     "loaded":true        
  },
  {
     "amount":-20.34,
     "dealDate":"10/16/15 11:53 AM",
     "dealName":"Deal 1b",
     "id":"3",
     "parent":"1", 
     "level":"1", 
     "isLeaf":true, 
     "loaded":true 
  },
  {
     "amount":25,
     "dealDate":"10/16/15 11:53 AM",
     "dealName":"Deal 2",
     "id":"4",
     "parent":"null", 
     "level":"0", 
     "isLeaf":false, 
     "loaded":true           
  }
 ]
}
```

And the jQgrid definition: (with the treeGrid options removed (commented out))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {

    var mydata ;
        $.getJSON( "sampleData.json", function( data ) {
          mydata=$.extend(true, [], data.data) ;

    console.log("Initial JSON data:\n" + JSON.stringify(mydata));

         $("#list").jqGrid({
         data: mydata,           
         datatype: "local",
         mtype: "GET",
         colNames: ["id", "Title", "Amount", "Date", "","","",""],
         colModel: [                    
             { name: "id", width: 55, hidden: true},                 
             { name: "dealName", width: 90, editable: true },
             { name: "amount", width: 80, align: "right",editable: true },
             { name: "dealDate", width: 80, align: "right", editable: true }
            { name: "parent", width: 80, align: "right", hidden: true },
            { name: "level", width: 80, align: "right", hidden: true },
             { name: "isLeaf", width: 80, align: "right", hidden: true },
             { name: "loaded", width: 80, align: "right", hidden: true }
         ],
         editurl: 'clientArray',
         cellsubmit : 'clientArray',             
         rowNum: 10,
         rowList: [10, 20, 30, 50],
         sortname: "id",
         viewrecords: true,
         gridview: true,
 //              treeGrid: true,
 //              ExpandColumn: 'dealName',
 //              treeGridModel:'adjacency',                  
         width: $(window).width() *0.55,
         caption: "Deal Test Grid"      
     });
    $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', "#pager", { edit: false, add: false, del:   
     false });
     $("#list").jqGrid('gridResize');
      });
  }); 
 </script>
```

And this produces perfectly fine grid !!
[image]
HOWEVER !!! 
Once I remove comments from tree grid parameters, my grid is NOT loaded !!
[image]

I have tried with adding and with removing of quotes around null value of a parent where there is no parent

```
         "parent":"null", vs.          "parent":null,
```

No avail !! Same results !!
Please, help !! What is it called - that thing that I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your code. First of all, it's the syntax error in `colModel`: no comma after the item which defines the column `dealDate`. The next problem: the input data should contains `id`, `parent`, `level`, `isLeaf` and `isLeaf`, but you should not define any columns in `colModel` with the names. The last important problem: you need include `treeGrid: true, treeGridModel: "adjacency", ExpandColumn: "dealName"` and optionally `ExpandColClick: true` to make the grid be TreeGrid.

The resulting code could be

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    colNames: ["Title", "Amount", "Date"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "dealName", width: 100 },
        { name: "amount", width: 80, template: "number" },
        { name: "dealDate", width: 180, align: "right", sorttype: "date",
            formatter: "date",
            formatoptions: { srcformat: "n/j/Y g:i A", newformat: "n/j/Y g:i A" } }
    ],
    cmTemplate: { width: 80, autoResizable: true, editable: true },
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    treeGrid: true,
    treeGridModel: "adjacency",
    ExpandColumn: "dealName",
    ExpandColClick: true,
    inlineEditing: { keys: true },
    ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
        var $self = $(this), savedRow = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
        if (savedRow.length > 0 && savedRow[0].id !== rowid) {
            $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRow[0].id);
        }
        $self.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, { focusField: e.target });
    }
}).jqGrid("gridResize");
```

where I included starting inline editing on double-click. The resulting demo can be find [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/LocalAdjacencyTree-DimaR.htm). It uses free jqGrid 4.10.0, which I published today. The code is already available on CDNs (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).

Comment: Thanks, Oleg.  That "No coma, was a typo in here on a website.  I did not copy it over.  I did have it in my files.  I tried your code and it did not work initially !!  I gigged through your example and realized that you are using different libraries.  Once, I started using what you use, I have my example working.  
So, there is something fundamentally conceptual that I am missing ... what is it I have to pay attention to, when dealing with jQueries/jqGrids liraries?  I have few versions downloaded, etc... They are not older or at least not very old verison.  SO, I would expect them working OK

Comment: @DimaR.: You are welcome! Is the problem is solved now and you see TreeGrid on your website?

Comment: Yes ..thank you. This stage of a problem is solved.  What I did not know before, is that I don't have to use parent, level, etc in my column model.  Useful lesson.